# amazing DBA create hard queries, and implement it on Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I do not have much experience with EF5, and my DBA generates just awful complexity queries, and I was very limited in the choice of tools.
I will describe the problem.
The database is not normalized so that such queries is a necessity. And I can not influence its structure and queries
For example i have query:

```
SELECT A.my_id, 
    A.field_1, 
    A.field_2, 
    A.field_3, 
    A.field_4, 
    A.field_5, 
    A.field_6,
    A.field_7, 
    A.field_8, 
    A.field_9, 
    B.field_10, 
    C.field_11, 
    C.field_12,
    C.field_13, 
    C.field_14, 
    D.field_15, 
    E.my_id2, 
    E.field_16, 
    E.field_17, 
    E.field_18, 
    G.field_19
    etc...
FROM tbl1 A, 
tbl2 B, tbl3 C, tbl4 D, tbl5 E, tbl6 F, tbl7 G
WHERE A.my_id                   = B.my_id
  AND A.my_id                   = C.my_id
  AND A.my_id                   = D.my_id
  AND A.my_id                   = E.my_id
  AND E.my_id3                  = F.my_id3
  AND E.my_id4                  = G.my_id4
  AND E.my_id2                  = <value from code>
  AND F.param1                  = <value from code>
  AND B.param4                  = 'KEY1'
  AND B.param5                  = 'KEY2'
  AND E.param8                  > 0 
  AND E.param9                  = 'KEY3'
  AND E.param10                 <> 'KEY4'       
  AND G.param11                 = 'KEY5'
  AND G.param12                 <= <SYSTEM DATETIME>
  AND G.param13                 >= <SYSTEM DATETIME>
  AND A.param2                  <= <SYSTEM DATETIME>
  AND A.param3                  >= <SYSTEM DATETIME>
  AND B.param6                  <= <SYSTEM DATETIME>
  AND B.param7                  >= <SYSTEM DATETIME>`
```

Now I will describe the problems that I encountered when moving the queries in code using Entity Framework 5.

I do INNER JOIN to a main table. Like this.

```
ObjectContext.CreateQuery<ETbl5>(entityName).
.Where(E =>
    E.param2 >= SqlFunctions.GetDate() && E.param3 <= SqlFunctions.GetDate() &&
    E.param8 > 0 && E.param9 == "KEY3" &&
    E.param10 != "KEY4" && E.my_id2 == <value from code>
)
.Join((Context as MyDbContext).ETbl7 ,
    E => new { A.my_id4},
    G => new { B.my_id4},
    (E, G) => E
)
```

How do I add conditions for JOIN as `AND G.param12 <= <SYSTEM DATETIME>`? How can I add such conditions in an anonymous type?

I have always a lot of problems and I think im on wrong way. Perhaps in addition to solving the problem, you can tell me the correct Strategy for dealing with such queries.
I understand that it can be transferred to a stored procedure, but the output I want to have the result that IQuerable to use it in Grid with Pagination.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a little bit different approach: create a view in your database based on your DBA's query and map it to your Entity Framework model. You will get benefit of IQueriable and you will not need to transform all these complicated queries. Moreover, you will not be responsible for possible errors you introduce during the query transformation (from SQL to LINQ)